# Facebook like button slow down website loading time

Tags: javascript, facebook

Here is my code:

```
<body>
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <!-- start JavaScript SDK code -->
 <script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
 </script>
  <!-- end JavaScript SDK code -->
  <div class="fb-like"  
  data-href="https://www.facebook.com/EminenceSystem" 
  data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" 
  data-show-faces="true" data-share="true">
 </div>
</body>
```

I put the JS-SDK code after body tag and FaceBook like button code at the    footer section. The result is shown which I want but the website loading time is slow down, how I increase the page speed for fast loading?

Comment: Most social share integration make 3+ requests, not to mention the DOM repaints/reflows. Try https://github.com/kni-labs/rrssb